# z-index issue with ng-grid's column menu

Tags: html, angularjs, css, z-index, ng-grid

When I put two ng-grids on the same page and open the colum menu for the first one, the second grid's header overlaps it as seen in this screenshot:

[image: ng-grid screenshot]

I've tried setting the `z-index` on the column menu to a very high value but it had no effect. I've tried several other approaches but I'm clearly missing something. Any suggestions? Plunker demonstrating the behaviour here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Eb3BL0l01GHXLvVSGTA5

Comment: Does your menu have a `position: relative` or `position: absolute` property?

Comment: @doitmyway - the source for ng-grid is on github. Here's a link to the column menu template (shown above): https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/master/src/templates/menuTemplate.html

Comment: See here for developer comments from the issue post on the official forum:  https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/1035

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Force the z-index of the first grid panel with this CSS style

```
[ng-grid=gridOptions1] .ngTopPanel {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

[demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/EIEmQkKwC45omGkgOLwJ?p=preview)

A better approach (as suggested in comments) is to use a nth-child approach. extended to 3 items:

```
.gridStyle:first-child .ngTopPanel {
     z-index: 3;
}
.gridStyle:nth-child(2) .ngTopPanel {
     z-index: 2;
}
```

[demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/alw2snzER454AYT1iO15?p=preview)

Comment: Is there a more general solution for if there are more than 2 grids stacked up below each other? (Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/cD27SSMpXs3Q0genXzDk?p=preview)

Comment: In theory, all grids can use the same grid options too, so a proper solution will probably either have to apply a unique id to each grid element, or somehow make use of the CSS' ability to identify the number of a child. (Upvoted btw. I'm asking because I work with pmdarrow.)

Answer (score 0):

Adding `z-index:0` to the second div with the classes `ngTopPanel ng-scope` helps. (tested in Chrome)

Comment: Thank's but I need something that applies works with more than just 2 grids stacked on eachother.

Comment: Plus setting the z-index to 0 will probably have other unintended side effects when using various ng-grid features that display overlaying controls.

Comment: You got a point there. I was just looking at this particular case, so yeah, better use the other solution.